# How to increment value in dynamic event handler with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I have a 4 squares in which each square holds individual state. Attached to each square is a dynamic event handler that will increment their individual state. I'm not implementing the dynamic logic correctly as the state does not increment upon a square's button click. What am I doing wrong?

```
export const Board = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState({
    squareOne: 0,
    squareTwo: 0,
    squareThree: 0,
    squareFour: 0
  });

  const handleIncrement = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { name, value }
    } = event;
    setSquares({ ...squares, [name]: value + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="board">
      <Square value={squares.squareOne} increment={handleIncrement} />
      <Square value={squares.squareTwo} increment={handleIncrement} />
      <Square value={squares.squareThree} increment={handleIncrement} />
      <Square value={squares.squareFour} increment={handleIncrement} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Square = ({ value, increment }) => {
  return <button onClick={increment}>{value}</button>;
};
```

Comment: you hadn't have  used `name` properly

Comment: @MohammadBarbast Could you kindly explain?

Comment: I left you a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specified number of squares you better have this:

```
export const Board = () => {
    const [squareOne, setSquareOne] = useState(0)
    const [squareTwo, setSquareTwo] = useState(0)
    const [squareThree, setSquareThree] = useState(0)
    const [squareFour, setSquareFour] = useState(0)



    return (
        <div className="board">
            <Square value={squareOne} increment={() => setSquareOne(squareOne + 1)} />
            <Square value={squareTwo} increment={() => setSquareTwo(squareTwo + 1)} />
            <Square value={squareThree} increment={() => setSquareThree(squareThree + 1)} />
            <Square value={squareFour} increment={() => setSquareFour(squareFour + 1)} />
        </div>
    );
};

export const Square = ({ value, increment }) => {
    return <button onClick={increment}>{value}</button>;
};
```

Otherwise if number of your squares is dynamic you can do this:

```
export const Board = () => {
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState([
        { id: 1, value: 0 },
        { id: 2, value: 0 },
        { id: 3, value: 0 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]);

    const handleIncrement = (id) => {
        const targetSquare = squares.find(s => s.id === id)
        targetSquare.value = targetSquare.value + 1;
        setSquares([...squares])
    }

    return (
        <div className="board">
            {squares.map((s, i) => <Square key={i} value={s.value} increment={() => handleIncrement(s.id)} />)}
        </div>
    );
};

export const Square = ({ value, increment }) => {
    return <button onClick={increment}>{value}</button>;
};
```

This is my preferences, feel free to do it any way.

Answer (score 2):

```
  export const Board = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState({
    squareOne: 0,
    squareTwo: 0,
    squareThree: 0,
    squareFour: 0
  });

  const handleIncrement = (name) => () => {
    setSquares({ ...squares, [name]: squares[name] + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="board">
      <Square value={squares.squareOne} increment={handleIncrement('squareOne')} />
      <Square value={squares.squareTwo} increment={handleIncrement('squareTwo')} />
      <Square value={squares.squareThree} increment={handleIncrement('squareThree')} />
      <Square value={squares.squareFour} increment={handleIncrement('squareFour')} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Square = ({ value, increment }) => {
  return <button onClick={increment}>{value}</button>;
};
```

You are not making use of name property. In the solution handle Increment takes the name and returns a function that will increment that part of the state by making use of "closures". This way your code will work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!